# Selecting a row where, 1=a, 2=b OR 1=b, 2=a

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a form that is giving me information like `INPUT1, INPUT2.  I need to select from COL1 and COL2 where COL1 = INPUT1, COL2 = INPUT2` or the other way around, `COL1 = INPUT2, COL2 = INPUT1.`

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
                      (COL1 = INPUT1 AND COL2 = INPUT2) 
                   OR (COL1 = INPUT2 AND COL2 = INPUT1);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE ( COL1=INPUT1 AND COL2=INPUT2 ) 
   OR ( COL1=INPUT2 AND COL2=INPUT1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from table_name
where ( COL1=INPUT1 AND COL2=INPUT2 )  OR ( COL1=INPUT2 AND COL2=INPUT1 ) ;